# When I resize a layer of imageview, how can I resize the uiimageview at the same time?

Tags: iphone, imageview, scale, layer, cabasicanimation

this is my code:

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation 
                               animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
[animation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f]];
[animation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.0f]];
[animation setDuration:0.8];
[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
[animation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
[imageView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"scale"];

[imageView setFrame:nowRect];
```

I find that this not right, because when I set the imageView frame as nowRect, the layer of imageView become bigger again!

Comment: hi what is your actual need ....

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, my English is so bad. I want to make the imageview's frame to be the frame which the imageview's layer is showed in after the animation.

Comment: what is the frame size your having after and before ....

Comment: For example, the old frame is (x, y,width, height). the new frame is (x, y, width*3, height*3).After the animation, I want to set the imageview's frame as same as its layer's frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this u first set your image size in viewDidLoad....

for example: 
in this example a and b are your require size initially...

```
imageForAnimate.frame=CGRectMake(imageForAnimate.frame.origin.x, imageForAnimate.frame.origin.y, a, b);
```

then the you need to append this code the area you need...

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 animations:^{
        imageForAnimate.frame=CGRectMake(imageForAnimate.frame.origin.x, imageForAnimate.frame.origin.y, a*3, b*3);


    }];
```

i hope this will help you to solve ....

Comment: Thanks for you!! I just want to know when I use the animation of layer, how to make the view's frame move to the frame which the layer of the view is located in. but the animation your answer say is what I want.